# "else if" is not working in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, fadein, fadeout

I have written an if statement in jQuery.

My code:

```
if($('#customer0').checked())
{
  $('#shop').fadeOut();
}

else if($('#customer1').checked())
{
  $('#shop').fadeIn();
}

else ($('#customer2').checked())
{
  $('#shop').fadeOut();
};
```

When I have `if (custmer0)` and `else (customer1)` the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` work good. But when it's `customer2` (that is else statement) it is not working? What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

else doesn't take any parameters. The code below is more applicable:

```
if($('#customer0').checked()) { $('#shop').fadeOut(); }
else if($('#customer1').checked()) { $('#shop').fadeIn(); }
else if($('#customer2').checked()) { $('#shop').fadeOut(); };
```

Answer (score 1):

On your third else

Change

```
else ($('#customer2').checked())
```

to

```
else if ($('#customer2').checked())
```

Answer (score 0):

fix you parens:

```
if ($('#customer0').checked()) {
    $('#shop').fadeOut();
}

else {
    if ($('#customer1').checked()) {
        $('#shop').fadeIn();
    }

    else {
       if($('#customer2').checked()) {
          $('#shop').fadeOut();
       }
    }
}
```

The reason why you code want working is the if statement was taking the wrong else for when the if statement is `false`

Also you cannot have params for an `else` statement

Comment: @George Bailey, i fixed that ^_^

Answer (score 0):

First off, the syntax for getting the value of a checkbox is:

```
$('#customer0').attr('checked')
```

Second, `else` statements don't have `(statement)` after them, you need to use a `else if`.

```
if($('#customer0').attr('checked'))
{
  $('#shop').fadeOut();
}

else if($('#customer1').attr('checked'))
{
  $('#shop').fadeIn();
}

else if($('#customer2').attr('checked'))
{
  $('#shop').fadeOut();
}
```